# How do I use this fetchRequest() in Swift?

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am new to `swift`. I am trying to create a core data `NSManagedObject` class as I used to do in `Objective-C`.

In Objective-C I would create something like

```
+ (Countries *)countryWithName:(NSString *)name
 inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {

  NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
  request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:NSStringFromClass([self class])
                               inManagedObjectContext:context];


  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                            @"(country == %@)", name];

  request.predicate = predicate;

  return [[context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil] lastObject];
}
```

So, at any time I would like to fetch a country by name on core data, I would do

```
userCountry = [Countries countryWithName:@"United States" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

But after creating a `NSManagedObject` class using swift, I see Xcode created this code inside `Countries+CoreDataProperties.swift`

```
@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Countries> {
    return NSFetchRequest<Countries>(entityName: "Countries")
}

@NSManaged public var number: Int16
@NSManaged public var name: String?
@NSManaged public var shortcut: NSData?
```

Now I want to create my class `countryByName` function. The first line there should be

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Countries")
```

but `fetchRequest()` is already created.

how do I use that?

it will not let me use

```
let request = Countries.fetchRequest()
```

giving me an error `Ambiguous use of fetchRequest)=`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using two different entities `Countries` and `Atributos` in the `fetchRequest()` declaration. That indeed ambiguous. The entity must be unique.

```
@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Countries> {
    return NSFetchRequest<Countries>(entityName: "Countries")
}
```

and you have to use it

```
let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<Countries> = Countries.fetchRequest()
```

Note: It's highly recommended to name entities in singular form. Semantically each record represents one `Country` not one `Countries`. Only to-many relationships are supposed to be named in plural form.

Comment: Sorry about the `Atributos`. That was a typo when I copied the class here. Change for the singular tip. THANKS

Comment: or simply `return .init(entityName: "Countries")`

Answer (score 4):

Fetch request is a generic so you must specify the type, like so:

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<Countries> = Countries.fetchRequest()
```

Comment: you meant `NSFetchRequest<Countries>`

Comment: Yes, sorry, just used to managed object being named singular.  Fixed.